# Get amount of a certain unique value within a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I tried:

### column1

33

33

62

59

`df.column1.unique().value_counts()`

```
>> 33 2

   62 1

   59 1
```

It gives the information, but if I have say 3000 unique values within that column then it's very tedious to find the value I'm looking for. How would I go about finding, say the amount of 33's in column1 if column1 was huge?